# Unable to parse json output by JMESPATH

Tags: json, azure, azure-cli, jmespath

I am running the below azure cli command to get the subscription ids for a particular management group.

**Command:**

```
az account management-group show --name "Simple-NonProduction-EMG-v01" -e -r
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "children": [
    {
      "children": null,
      "displayName": "TestSub-ABC-Dev",
      "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "roles": null,
      "type": "/subscriptions"
    },
    {
      "children": null,
      "displayName": "TestSubIdentity",
      "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "roles": null,
      "type": "/subscriptions"
    },
    {
      "children": null,
      "displayName": "TestSub-Build-DevTest",
      "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "roles": null,
      "type": "/subscriptions"
    },
    {
      "children": null,
      "displayName": "Azure ITI - TestSub Pre-prod",
      "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "roles": null,
      "type": "/subscriptions"
    },
    {
      "children": null,
      "displayName": "TestSub-IS-Demo",
      "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "roles": null,
      "type": "/subscriptions"
    },
    {
      "children": null,
      "displayName": "TestSub-PQR-QA",
      "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "roles": null,
      "type": "/subscriptions"
    },
    {
      "children": null,
      "displayName": "TestSub-PQR-PreProd",
      "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "roles": null,
      "type": "/subscriptions"
    }
  ],
  "details": {
    "parent": {
      "displayName": "Simple-DMG-v01",
      "id": "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/Simple-DMG-v01",
      "name": "Simple-DMG-v01"
    },
    "updatedBy": null,
    "updatedTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "version": 0.0
  },
  "displayName": "Simple-NonProduction-EMG-v01",
  "id": "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/Simple-NonProduction-EMG-v01",
  "name": "Simple-NonProduction-EMG-v01",
  "roles": null,
  "tenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "type": "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups"
}
```

I run the below commands but it gives **no output**.

```
az account management-group show --name "Simple-NonProduction-EMG-v01" -e -r --query [].[children]
az account management-group show --name "Simple-NonProduction-EMG-v01" -e -r --query [].[children.children.name]
az account management-group show --name "Simple-NonProduction-EMG-v01" -e -r --query [].[children.children]
```

I do not understand

1. Why I am not getting the output.
2. When to use square brackets against when to use single quotes.

**No output** for the below command as well:

```
az account management-group show --name "Simple-NonProduction-EMG-v01" -e -r --query 'children.children.name'
```

Reference to use single quotes:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest

Reference to use square brackets:
https://adamraffe.com/azure/2017/11/22/the-wonderful-world-of-azure-cli-jmespath-queries/

I would appreciate your input.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing it this way:

```
az account management-group show --name "Simple-NonProduction-EMG-v01" -e -r --query `children`
```

and like this:

```
az account management-group show --name "Simple-NonProduction-EMG-v01" -e -r --query 'children[].name'
```

Comment: Does not work. Back tick gives command not found. children.name returns no output. I tried single quotes instead of back ticks and it gives children, unfortunately, children.name does not still give me subscription ids.

Comment: well, because for id's you need to use `'children.id'` if you want id's, obviously; its quotes, not backticks

Comment: No idea why it is not working. Tried with 'children.id' still no charm...

Comment: ah right, sorry, it has to be `children[].id`, since children is an array of objects

Comment: Thanks I get it and is working but still not what I want. 
Example
```
az vm list --query [].[name] -otable
```
This command gives me a list of all VMs in a subscription. That is much preferred as then I can use something like head -2 to get list of VM names easily.

Comment: what do you mean: `still not what I want`. this is exactly what you are asking for

Comment: I accept this as right answer. Updated the answer as well.